# How to select a group of children from the parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a `Parent` component which renders a set of `Child` components. When hovering one of those `Child` component, I wish to highlight (bg color) the `Child` components that belong in the same group.

See code below, each `Child` has a group property:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/53442/

```
const Parent = React.createClass({
    render() {
        const rows = [];
        let group = 1;
        for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            rows.push(<Child key={i} id={i} group={group} />);

            if (i % 3 === 0) {
                group++;
            }
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                {rows}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});

const Child = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <li className="child">id: {this.props.id} - group: {this.props.group}</li>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

If I hover `Child` with id property of 6, how do I highlight all of the `Child` components which are in the same group, i.e. group 2 ?

NB: I'm new to React and sorry if the title is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd approach this with local state like so:

In a nutshell, we are generating a state variable for the current group on the parent. Then we give each child a proxy method it calls on `onMouseEnter` where it passes its `group` prop to the parent method. Then, each render compares the active group versus its own group and sets the active prop on the child. The child then checks its active prop to apply an `active` class. Obviously you can extend this behavior by a lot. Check out the Event System of React, [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events).

This fiddle is a very rudimentary example of how it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/53444/

## CSS

```
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

## JS

```
const Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            group: null
        }
    },

    render() {
        const rows = [];
        let group = 1;

        for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            const child = <Child 
              key={i}
              id={i}
              group={group} 
              hover={(group) => this.setState({ group })}
              active={group === this.state.group} />;

            rows.push(child);

            if (i % 3 === 0) {
                group++;
            }
        }

        return (
            <ul>
                {rows}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});

const Child = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <li 
              className={this.props.active && 'active'}
              onMouseEnter={() => this.props.hover(this.props.group)}
            >
                id: {this.props.id} - group: {this.props.group}
            </li>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: that's great. Could you please explain me how this code works? `className={this.props.active && 'active'}`

Comment: Sure! This pretty much "short circuits" the evaluation to assign a class name. Since `active` is a boolean prop passed to the component, we can evaluate against it. Should it be `true` it will continue the evaluation and assign the string `active` (in this case, our class name). In case it is `false`, it will stop there and not assign a class at all). I've seen this pattern a lot in React when you either want to assign something or nothing at all (in contrast to a ternary operator). Hope this clears it up!

Comment: As an addition, you could write it like so: `className={this.props.active ? 'active' : ''}`. Both approaches are equivalent. I just happen to like the former better.

Comment: Thank you, I also found a useful and popular package for manipulating class attributes: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

Answer (score 3):

Well, It could be done by simple css code + some react modifications.
First, if you have few groups that means lists of groups, which means list of lists.
You would have the Container component, Group component, and GroupItem component.
the Container will render few Group components which will render few GroupItem components.

It would be something like this:

```
export default class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(<ul>
            {this.state.groups.map((group) => {
                return <Group items={group.items} />
            })}
        </ul>)
    }
}

export default class Group extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<ul>
            {this.props.items.map((item) => {
                return <GroupItem />
            })}
        </ul>)
    }
}

export default class GroupItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<li>some content here</li>);
    }
}
```

now give each Group a class that when you hover will highlight the sons:

```
.group:hover > li {
    background-color: color;
}
```

now when you will hover the group, which is like hovering a single item but applies to all the items, all of its children will be highlighted

Comment: Thank you. I simplified the real case a lot ; actually I don't even use lists, but css grids. Adding a Group component in between makes things complicated in my case. is there any other possible option?

Comment: It'll be a bit difficult to share code right now. The thing is that I want the css grid to be as simple as possible. Your solution is the best if applicable, so I upvoted. Accepted Mario's because it just suits better for my specific case. Thx!